# Compare NSArray elements to NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, arrays, if-statement

I'm new to objective c. I am getting my data from an `NSArray` and want to return value according to some condition. My code is:

```
  NSArray *myData;
  NSNumber *day = 5;

  myData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"5", nil];

  for (int i = 0; i < [myData count]; i++) {
      if(day == myData[0]){
      NSLog(@"date in valueForDay %@ ", da );
       return 3;
   }
 }
```

Above code doesn't execute my statements (`NSLog` and `return` one).
But if i statically compare day with any number it got executed. Like:

```
  NSArray *myData;
  NSNumber *day = 5;

  myData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"5", nil];

  for (int i = 0; i < [myData count]; i++) {
      if(day == 5){
      NSLog(@"date in valueForDay %@ ", da );
       return 3;
   }
 }
```

can anyone please tell me where i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created array with string value not with number value. That's why object from your array is `"5"` which is not equal to integer 5. Make your array as number array.

```
myData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @5, nil];
```

Also instead of for loop you can simply use [`indexOfObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1417076-indexofobject) to check array having object or not.

```
NSInteger index = [myData indexOfObject: day];
if(index != NSNotFound) {
    return 3;
}
```

Comment: thanks , also can you tell me what to do if my day variable is an integer?

Comment: @DeepakVerma Welcome mate :), if day is integer you can make `NSNumber` object from it `NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:day];`

Answer (score 0):

You stored NSString in NSArray. And comparing with NSNumber. You have to add one line above if condition and change your condition.

```
NSString *myString = [day stringValue];
if([myString isEqualToString:myData[0]])
```